# Where can I find Aravinay?

Tags: genshin-impact

Aravinay is a vendor in Vanarana that trades blueprints for craftable weapons in exchange for stories with the Aranara. I have completed the World of Aranara series of quests and now all of the Aranara have disappeared, including Aravinay!

Where can I find Aravinay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get back to Mahavanaranapna (for example, after you complete the World of Aranara series of quests), you need to perform the Rhythm of the Great Dream to the silapna in Vanarana.

[image: The silapna in Vanarana]

Once you are back inside the dream, you can find Aravinay stood in front of the Tree of Dreams.

Comment: To be fair, shouldn't that work at any time even if you didn't finish the whole quests series? Also, there is an Amber missing in the party, that should be an implicit prerequisite when using Collei :P

Comment: makes sense to me, I did the world of aranara in basically one go so never ended up part way through the quest and needing to get back in